# Ansible dictionary key as variable

Tags: automation, continuous-integration, ansible, jinja2

Let's have something like this in role defaults/main.yml:

```
num: 0
config:
  0:
    a: true
    b: 'x'
  1:
    a: false
    b: 'y'
  2:
    a: false
    b: 'z'
```

Now I send `-e num=1` in playbook call, and I want to use values `a` and `b` based on this value somewhere else in the role, something like:

```
aValue: '{{config[num].a}}'
bValue: '{{config[num].b}}'
```

How do I do that? I tried

`aValue: '{{config[num].a}}'`
but got an error: `'dict object' has no attribute u'1'`

`aValue: '{{config["num"].a}}'` 
but got an error: `'dict object' has no attribute 'num'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you quote those config keys, they will become strings:

```
config:
  "0":
     a: true
```

Or, if you have the rest of your playbook that really does want them to be numbers, you can make `num` *actually* be a number in two ways:

`ansible -e '{"num": 1}'` to cause ansible to parse `--extra-vars` as JSON, where `"num"` really will be a `Number` (in the JSON sense)

or coerce `num` in the jinja2 expression:

```
aValue: '{{ config[ (num|int) ].a }}'
```