# Ansible: json element strip key with colon

Tags: json, ansible, jinja2, element

How do you remove a json Key that contains a colon (:) with jinja2 rejectattr.

## Environment:

```
ansible 2.9.1
  config file = None
  configured module search path = [u'/home/<user>/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.15+ (default, Oct  7 2019, 17:39:04) [GCC 7.4.0]
```

json data:

```
   {
        "tag:environment": "qa", 
        "tag:instance_id": "i-123456789"
    }
```

## Ansible playbook:

```
- name: Remove InstanceID
  debug:
    msg:  "{{ instance_filter | rejectattr('['tag:environment'], 'defined' ') | list  }}
```

## Actual Results:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "template error while templating string: expected token ',', got 'tag'. String: {{ instance_filter | rejectattr('['tag:environment'], 'defined' ') | list  }}"
}
```

## Expected results:

```
   {
        "tag:environment": "qa"
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `rejectattr` is indeed one of the key filters to use to achieve your goal, but a few more things are needed. Here is the correct sequence of filters to remove that particular key from the dictionary variable you have:

### Playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    instance_filter:
      tag:environment: qa
      tag:instance_id: i-123456789

  tasks:
  - name: print var
    debug:
      var: instance_filter

  - name: manipulate the var
    debug:
      msg: "{{ instance_filter | dict2items | rejectattr('key', 'equalto', 'tag:instance_id') | list | items2dict }}"
```

### Output:

```
PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [print var] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "instance_filter": {
        "tag:environment": "qa",
        "tag:instance_id": "i-123456789"
    }
}

TASK [manipulate the var] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "tag:environment": "qa"
    }
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

hope it helps.

Comment: The snippet above works @ilias-sp.   However, I'm looking to have the output result with everything except "tag:instance_id": "i-123456789".    How can I get ""tag:environment": "qa""?

Comment: ops, i thought you wanted to remove the other one. please see updated answer @user3728043

Comment: In addition 'rejectattr' can get 'contains' and can be used to remove multiple keys from dict, example: rejectattr('key', 'contains', 'instance')

Answer (score 1):

> Q: *"How do you remove a JSON key?"*

A: It's possible to [create custom filter plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#filter-plugins). For example

```
$ cat filter_plugins/dict_utils.py
def dict_del_key(d, key):
    del d[key]
    return d

class FilterModule(object):
    ''' Ansible filters. Interface to Python dictionary methods.'''

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'dict_del_key' : dict_del_key
        }
```

The play below

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    dict:
      'tag:environment': 'qa' 
      'tag:instance_id': 'i-123456789'
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ dict|dict_del_key('tag:instance_id') }}"
```

gives

```
  msg:
    tag:environment: qa
```

---

Notes:

- See [If you quote those config keys, they will become strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53294414/ansible-dictionary-key-as-variable).
- See the difference between [7.3.1. Double-Quoted Style](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2787109) and [7.3.2. Single-Quoted Style](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2788097).
- FWIW. See other filters available at [GitHub](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-plugins).